# Vertical alignment of nested spans within div rows

Tags: css

Nothing I can find or have tried is working so I hope someone can tell me where I am going wrong.  I have a table-like HTML structure with `div` rows containing only `span` cells.  These in turn can contain either a single `span` or two rows of `span`s.  Unfortunately, for some reason I've been wrestling with on and off for weeks, the single `span` cells [do not align with the double-row cells](http://jsbin.com/gukon/1/edit).

The minimal HTML is:

```
    <div id="box">

        <div id="rowA" class="row">
            <span class="container">
                <span class="top">A</span>
                <span class="bottom">B</span>
            </span>
            <span class="container">
                <span class="single">C</span>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div id="rowB" class="row">
            <span class="container">
                <span class="top">D</span>
                <span class="bottom">E</span>
            </span>
            <span class="container">
                <span class="single">F</span>
            </span>
        </div>

    </div>
```

with CSS,

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
}
div#box {
    width: 716px;
    height: 255px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
div.row {
    width: 712px;
    height: 47px;
    padding: 1px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;}
span.container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;}
span.top, span.bottom {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height:  50%;
    line-height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
span.single {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The double row cells (e.g. `<span class="container"><span class="top">D</span><span class="bottom">E</span></span>`) display correctly, the single row cells are shifted downwards for some reason.  I know that I can use positioning to correct for the problem but I'd like to understand where I am going wrong.  It's tested on Chrome and Firefox and alas their inspectors leave me none the wiser.

All contributions very gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
}

div#box {
    width: 716px;
    height: 255px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
div.row {
    width: 712px;
    height: 47px;
    padding: 1px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
span.container {
    vertical-align:top;    /* ADD JUST THIS LINE */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
span.top, span.bottom {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height:  50%;
    line-height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
span.single {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Do you have any idea why that should make any difference?  After all, it's the same whether the container contains one double-sized or two rows...

Comment: @loadsamates you're welcome! No, it's not the same, the inner spans affect 'inline' positioning of other elements. Cause you set to your SPAN `.container` to be `display:inline-block` -> they become block-alike elements but in an inline-element-flow, where line-heights and letter-spacing dictate rules. As soon you set that property expect you'll also have to set some kind of `vertical-align` (top, middle, baseline... any that suits your needs).

Comment: Well, I thought I'd accounted for that by setting the `line-height` to 40px and (2x) 20px with font only 16px...  Also, I'd be surprised if I hadn't experimented with `vertical-align` at some stage but obviously not effectively, preferring to kick the problem down the line while I worked on other aspects. Ho hum, should've come here earlier.  Thank you for your sharing your wisdom once again. And thanks also for the links.

Comment: @loadsamates like you can see from the demo above it's not only line-height that would mess things but a simple margin applied to all span elements :) Any way, `vertical-align` for inline-block elements! ;)